# Use jQuery to insert a script which includes a function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to append a line of JavaScript to a div dynamically, but it seems that when I run the .append() call, the browser sees a function() call within that line as an actual function instead of an actual string:

```
var startDate = 0
...
function insertCalendar(){
    var divName = "div[name=StartDate" + startDateNum + "]";
    $(divName).append("<script>Calendar.setup({ trigger : 'StartDate" + startDateNum + "', inputField : 'StartDate" + startDateNum + "', onSelect : function() { this.hide() } });</script>");
    startDateNum++;
}
```

At the call to .append() the JavaScript console returns "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input," and it seems to mess with the function insertCalendar. I'm fairly certain I'm not missing a quote...

Let me know if this is too vague as this is my first question here. Thanks!

Comment: Why are you appending the script tag instead of simply calling the function directly?

Comment: I need multiple iterations of the included function for each calendar instance I have on the page.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a script tag, and then add the javascript.

```
  var jstag=document.createElement('script');
  jstag.setAttribute("type","text/javascript");
  jstag.appendChild(document.createTextNode(" Javascript code goes here  "));
  document.appendChild(jstag);
```

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer thanks to Anzz, mixed it with some AJAX:

```
var startDateNum = 0;
...
function setNewCal(){
var url = "getCal.php?startDate=" + startDateNum;
xmlHttp.open("GET", url, true);
xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = addCalendar;
xmlHttp.send(null);
}

function addCalendar(){
var divName = "StartDate" + startDateNum + "Div";
var response = xmlHttp.responseText;
if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4){
    var calscript = document.createElement("script");
    calscript.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
    calscript.appendChild(document.createTextNode(response));
    document.getElementById(divName).appendChild(calscript);
    startDateNum++;
    }
}
```